# Store nodes separately from edges when representing directed graphs in JSON to visualize in d3.js?

Tags: json, graph, d3.js, visualize

Should I store links separately from nodes, or should they be node properties?

Since nodes "have" edges, it seems like I should structure the data that way:

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"Homepage",
           "links":[{"name":"002","value":"1"}]},
          {"name":"FAQ"}
]}
```

But I can't render links until I have nodes, so it would seem like this structure forces me to analyze my whole graph twice. It also seems like popular d3 examples separate nodes from links, e.g.

```
 {"nodes":[{"name":"Homepage"},
           {"name":"FAQ"}],
  "links":[{"source":"Homepage","target":"FAQ","value":1}]
 }
```

Comment: D3.js tree functions take a structured input in the form of a nested JavaScript Object. For example, the root node should have a "children" array property with the node's linked children. If you're building up something more complicated (e.g., manually), then the nodes array is separate from the links array. D3.js convention is that the links array is a list of objects with similar to the links in your second example.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that pattern. What advantages does separating edges and vertices bring?

Comment: D3 effectively manipulates lists through its selections. Assuming your desired output is a collection of lines and circles, it makes sense to select all the circles and all the lines separately. This means applying data to selections in the same fashion (e.g., "selectAll('circle').data(vertices)", and "selectAll('line').data(edges)")